# Bind button Mediaelement

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, mediaelement

I have a video that I want to connect Play/Paus/Stop buttons to.
My code in my view is like this:

```
 <MediaElement Source="{Binding MediaUri}" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Visibility="{Binding IsIndexVisible, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolToHiddenConverter}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.877" Margin="0,0,0,19" />
    <Button x:Name="Play" Height="20" Width="40" Visibility="{Binding IsIndexVisible, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolToHiddenConverter}}"/>
```

My button should play video when clicked, but nothing happends.

In my viewmodel I have this code to the Playbutton and when I clicked on the button I come here in debug mode but nothing happends.

```
 public class MoviePlayerViewModel : TreeViewBase<MoviesViewModel>
{


public MoviePlayerViewModel(IDispatcherWrapper dispatcher, IViewManager viewManager, IKeyboardSimulator keyboardSimulator, IToggleInputManager toggleInputManager)
            : base(dispatcher, viewManager, keyboardSimulator, toggleInputManager)
        {
          UpdateGuards();

            ReadMediaFile();

            // Show course viewer at start
            IsIndexVisible = true;
        }

    public void Play(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
        mediaElement.Source = MediaUri;
        mediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        mediaElement.Play();
    }

        private Uri _mediaUri;
    public Uri MediaUri
    {
        get
        {
            return _mediaUri;
        }
        set
        {
            _mediaUri = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MediaUri);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsIndexVisible);
        }
    }
```

When I click on the button now I get to the Play method but nothing happends.

I´m using C# WPF and Caliburn micro.

Comment: Yes, my viewmodel is my code behinde

Comment: the solution below should work but I recommend you should also read some articles about MVVM and iCommands/RelayCommand to make your life easier in the future

Comment: One of your earlier comment puzzles me, Is Play() method written in Code behind or ViewModel ?

Comment: Play method is written in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MediaElement definition in XAML has a binding to MediaUri. So, it would play as soon as MediaUri is assigned. To work around it, you need to LoadedBehavior to your XAML.

```
LoadedBehavior="Manual"
```

Complete Code.

```
<MediaElement Source="{Binding MediaUri}" Visibility="{Binding IsIndexVisible, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolToHiddenConverter}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.877" Margin="0,0,0,19" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
```

To play the File using MediaElement with MVVM (and in your case Caliburn Micro), would require some more work.

**In ViewModel**

You need to declare a OnPlay event, and Invoke it in your Play Method.

```
public event EventHandler OnPlay;

public void Play()
{
    if(OnPlay!=null)
       this.OnPlay(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

**In View,**

Add a Loaded Event for your View

```
Loaded="Window_Loaded"
```

**In Code Behind File,**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

 var viewModelInstance = DataContext;
 (viewModelInstance as MainWindowViewModel).OnPlay += (s, ev) => {    this.MediaPlayer.Play(); };
}
```

Where MediaPlayer is the x:Name of your MediaElement.

Since the MediaElement doesn't allow us to Play the file from ViewModel, we create a work around with a hack in View. You create a Event in View, which is triggered on the Play method assigned to your Button. The View, in turn, plays the media file.

Comment: If I set LoadedBehavior to manual my movie does not show at all when I start the program.

Comment: Do you mean, if you set the LoadedBehavior, your video doesn't autoload. But, additionally the Play Method doesn't work ?

Comment: Yes, it does not autoload. No, the Play methos does not work :(

Comment: That has to be your view model. MoviePlayerViewModel

Comment: Glad to help you.